# JQuery new window with auto-execute script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to open a pre-determined webpage and execute a click event on it when it opens.

As an example, here's an experiment I did with a google power search:

```
$("#lnkSearch").click(function() {
    console.log("you clicked Search");
    $(this).attr("target", "_blank");

    // build the search
        var search = $("#txtSearch").val();         
    search = search + "+site%3Aloganyoung.za.net";

    $(this).attr("href", "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + search);
    //window.open($(this).attr("href"));

});
```

Now to add onto this, I have it in mind to open the first link in the search results automatically.

Is there a way that I can do this in the new window before I open it?

Comment: only if you create a browser plugin or extension

Comment: If the new window is a non-cooperating web page in a different domain, then the same-origin protections will keep you from modifying the page in any way from your other web page.  If it a cooperating web page, then you can use `postMessage()` to send a message to it which it can choose to act upon.

Comment: If this is really a question about programmatically operating on Google search results, then you should probably look at the [Google search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) and approach the problem that way.

Comment: jfriend00 so, considering the above, I could do `window.postMessage($('.somediv a:first').click());` ?